# My app can no longer find app.config

Tags: c#, wcf, app-config

I have created a windows forms application in c# to run on some Windows 10 tablets. This has been running on them for more than a year without having caused any problems. We have a total of three tablets. A few weeks ago one of the tablets needed to be repaired, while the other two is still being used. The newly repaired tablet was factory reset and has now a clean install of Windows 10 with the newest updates. For some reason when I run the application on the repaired tablet, it seems to fail when reading from the config file. All files are exactly the same on all tablets

In my application I am connecting to a WCF service. I'm using the below code to get the object for the connection:

```
return new SilverTruckService.SilverTruckServiceClient("TruckService1");
```

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySQL-MyDatabase" connectionString="BLABLABLA" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://SomeIPAddress:9001/TruckService"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TruckService"
        contract="TruckService.ITruckService" name="TruckService1" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

In the folder with the exe file I have the following two files:

Truck.exe
Truck.exe.config

The user has read/write access to the folder

To do a bit more testing to see if the problem was the config file or with the WCF service I ran the code below:

```
string tmp = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL-Database"].ConnectionString;
```

This one also fails. For some reason it seems like it can't find the config file or can't read from the config file

Remember this exact code runs perfectly fine on two other tablets also running Windows 10. 
Anybody who has any idea on what could be wrong?

Comment: Check if you have `System.Configuration`dll.

Comment: I set the dll to be copied local now it's in the same folder as the exe file, but doesn't make a difference

Comment: What error are getting then?

Comment: The code ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQL-Database"] returns null value. When trying to get the WCF service client I will get an InvalidOperationException. It is the same errors I get no matter if the config file is not present (For testing I tried to delete the config file) or if the I'm trying to get connectionstring or WCF client with a misspelled name (like writing CluckService55 instead of TruckService1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. I was searching the wrong place to find the error and the error seems to be far away from anything code related

My development machine and the tablet are not connected to each other. The tablet is only connected to internet through sim card. To easily transfer the application files from development machine to the tablet I have for the past year used Google Drive, which hasn't caused me any problems before

To Google drive I'm uploading the exe and the Truck.exe and Truck.exe.config files. Looking at them in Google Drive everything seems to be correct, but for some unknown reason Google Drive now decides to rename the Truck.exe.config file to Truck.exe.config.xml which I did not notice. This of course means my exe file can't find the config file

End result: Rename the file to it's original value and everything works as it should